# Understanding an equality that involves the gamma function

Tags: analysis, statistics, gamma-function

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\sigma^m \Gamma\left(\frac{m+1}{2}\right) 2^{\frac{m+1}{2}} = 2^{\frac{m}{2}}\sigma^m \left(\frac{m-1}{2}\right) \left(\frac{m-3}{2}\right)\cdots \left(\frac{3}{2}\right) \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$$

This equality is given in my lecture notes. What I can't understand is where the $\ \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\ $ went?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\Gamma\left(\frac{m+1}{2}\right) = \frac{m-1}{2}\cdot\frac{m-3}{2}\cdot\dotsc\cdot\frac{1}{2}\cdot\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right),$$

and $\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) = \sqrt{\pi}$. So it cancelled against $\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$.

Comment: Where did the $\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$ come from? I thought the factorial stopped at $\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: The functional equation is $\Gamma(z+1) = z\cdot\Gamma(z)$. So you get (as an example, to illustrate) $$\Gamma\left(\frac{5}{2}\right) = \frac{3}{2}\cdot\Gamma\left(\frac{3}{2}\right) = \frac{3}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2}\cdot\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right).$$ There is always a final $\Gamma$ factor when you expand $\Gamma(z+1)$ using the functional equation. Here, that factor cancels against the $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}$ from the original formula.

Comment: Appreciate the help mate